# How can one achieve an arbitrary frequency and duty cycle PWM-ed IR transmission in an xBee3 using MicroPython?

Tags: xbee, pwm, infrared, micropython, transmission

I am researching a way to send out a PWM-ed IR pulse from an xBee3 device. I couldn't find any IR related libs, so I guess I'll have to "brute" force it by "waiting" X many microseconds and setting digital I/O pins ON and OFF. 
Any ideas/pointers/references would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

MicroPython on the XBee3 RF products won't be capable of the microsecond timing you're looking for, and the PWM output only allows for setting the duty cycle, not the frequency.

You would need to add extra hardware to convert (for example) the I2C interface to IR transmission.  The XBee3 RF products don't support a secondary UART like the XBee Cellular products do, but if they add that feature you would could have a UART->IR interface via a secondary microprocessor.

Comment: So sleep_us() won't do it in an xBee3 RF module? :(

Comment: First off, you won't be able to control the PWM frequency which I think will be a requirement.  Also, because the XBee firmware has multiple tasks running (to process the 802.15.4 communications), you aren't going to have precise control over the I/O signals.  `sleep_us()` will sleep for at least that long, and likely longer due to overhead of MicroPython executing your code and the task potentially getting interrupted for milliseconds at a time.

Comment: I suspect the same, after some fiddling with the xBee3 :) Thank you @tomlogic!